# Filtering a collection of items from contents of another collection

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, collections

This used to work for me and then it failed. I want to return only those items that contain all the filters, not at least one filter as it is doing now. WHat is wrong here?

```
private IQueryable<IndexItem> FilteredIndex (IQueryable<IndexItem> index, IEnumerable<string> filters)

    {

        var filteredIndex= from f in filters.AsQueryable() 
               where f.Length>0
               from i in index 
               where i.FilterNames.Contains(f)
               select i;
        return filteredIndex;
   }
```

Comment: Which LINQ provider are you using? I assume it's not LINQ to Objects, based on the use of IQueryable.

Comment: I can give a quite elegant solution for LINQ to Objects, but I am not sure if it works for you. Let me hear if it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
foreach(string s in filters) {
    if(s.Length == 0) continue;
    string tmp = s; // because of "capture" problem
    index = index.Where(i => i.FilterNames.Contains(tmp));
}
return index;
```

This applies a succession of `Where` clauses, covering all the filters - essentially `AND`.

Comment: @zsharp the lambda inside of Where() is a closure. the variable s for that iteration must be kept otherwise it'll be different by the time Where lambda is executed. See closures.

Comment: Because we use "s" in a lambda, it is actually treated (by the compiler) as a field on a compiler-generated class (for complex reasons). The problem is that the nature of "foreach" means that otherwise you'd only get one of them, and you'd have n times Where([last filter]).

Answer (score 3):

Straight forward. For a given item from index check that it is true for all filters that the given item contains the filter. With this just select all items from index for that the given condition is true.

```
index.Where(item => 
   filters.All(filter => item.FilterNames.Contains(filter)))
```

I am not sure if the check for length greater than zero is required, nut it is easily integrated.

```
index.Where(item => 
   filters.All(filter =>
      (filter.Length > 0 ) || (item.FilterNames.Contains(filter))))
```

It works with LINQ to Objects and I guess it does what you want, but I am not sure if it works with LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Turn it around. What you want is those items in index where every item in FilterNames has a corresponding entry in filters. I'm not sure how performant it'd be, but a count comparison should do. Something like:

```
private IQueryable<IndexItem> FilteredIndex(IQueryable<IndexItem> index, IEnumerable<string> filter)
{
    var filteredIndex = from i in index
                        where (from s in i.FilterNames
                               where filter.Contains(s)
                               select s).Count() == i.FilterNames.Count
                        select i;
    return filteredIndex;
}
```